# Do Network Permissions apply to the Local Computer Too?

Tags: permissions, lan

If, say, I were to say that only a certain account were allowed to read a folder on an external drive, and then I were to take the external drive to another computer, would it be able to read the folder?

I ask because I'm attempting to use Windows Backup over a LAN.

Context: Windows 7 Professional, connected over a generic WiFi router. Windows Backup complains of not having permissions to the `WindowsImageBackup` folder on the external drive.

Comment: I will probably be able to answer your question, but I am having trouble understanding how the LAN comes into play with first part of the question with regards to the external drive here.

Comment: Windows permissions? OS is important.

Answer (score 0):

I may change this if you add additional information, which changes the scenario significantly.

If you really lock down a directory on an external drive so only one account can read it (usually externals allow everyone full access by default), let's say even a common account like administrator, and then you move it to another computer, even the administrator on the new computer will not be able to read it. The reason is that even though they have the same username, they have different SSID's (security identifiers), so are actually different in the eyes of the OS.

You may find that pass-through authentication may allow the new administrator to see it, that is, if they both have the same username and password. Of course, on a network, if you are talking a domain administrator, even if you gave it the permissions locally, that is the same user and SSID on another domain computer. Lastly, there is no real security, since if you plug that into any Windows computer, any administrator can take ownership of all the files, and then give himself any permissions they want.

Comment: Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here you want to use backup to a network share. Thru the UI its not possible to use a network share however here is a good post about how to do that:

http://www.ausweblogs.com/users/rodneyfletcher/?category_name=windows-admin

I have only tried this on sever 2008 installs but should be the same as the backup technology used is the same.

Comment: The thing is I'm backing up to a drive connected to a regular (albeit permanently docked) laptop running Windows 7.

Comment: Was the backup folder on that drive created by the machine it is current connected to or another system?